# Rails TypeError: can't modify immutable index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm rather stumped by this one. It seems like it's a sprockets error that I'm hitting when trying to push to Heroku. The only thing I've done since my last push a day ago was added in the clockwork gem and associated `lib/clock.rb` and `lib/clock_events_worker.rb` files.

Any ideas what I should check? I haven't touched any CSS.

```
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        TypeError: can't modify immutable index
remote:        /tmp/build_76f6fceeb8ba577abcf815781a45737e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/index.rb:81:in `expire_index!'
remote:        /tmp/build_76f6fceeb8ba577abcf815781a45737e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/base.rb:175:in `register_preprocessor'
remote:        /tmp/build_76f6fceeb8ba577abcf815781a45737e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/js-routes-1.2.2/lib/js_routes/engine.rb:11:in `block in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_76f6fceeb8ba577abcf815781a45737e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_76f6fceeb8ba577abcf815781a45737e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
remote:        /tmp/build_76f6fceeb8ba577abcf815781a45737e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
remote:        /tmp/build_76f6fceeb8ba577abcf815781a45737e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_76f6fceeb8ba577abcf815781a45737e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
remote:        /tmp/build_76f6fceeb8ba577abcf815781a45737e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:62:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
remote:        /tmp/build_76f6fceeb8ba577abcf815781a45737e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_76f6fceeb8ba577abcf815781a45737e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_76f6fceeb8ba577abcf815781a45737e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_76f6fceeb8ba577abcf815781a45737e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_76f6fceeb8ba577abcf815781a45737e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
remote:        /tmp/build_76f6fceeb8ba577abcf815781a45737e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
remote:        /tmp/build_76f6fceeb8ba577abcf815781a45737e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
remote:        /tmp/build_76f6fceeb8ba577abcf815781a45737e/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_76f6fceeb8ba577abcf815781a45737e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_76f6fceeb8ba577abcf815781a45737e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_76f6fceeb8ba577abcf815781a45737e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_76f6fceeb8ba577abcf815781a45737e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_76f6fceeb8ba577abcf815781a45737e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
remote:        /tmp/build_76f6fceeb8ba577abcf815781a45737e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:443:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_76f6fceeb8ba577abcf815781a45737e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution seemed to be adding sprockets to my gemfile. After that it pushed just fine.

`gem 'sprockets', '~> 3.0'`

Answer (score 0):

In your file `environments/development.rb` , `environments/production.rb` etc., ensure that following values are set:

```
config.assets.debug = false
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.digest = true
```

Comment: I tried setting those in `development.rb`, `staging.rb` and `production.rb`, but no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because I was doing some production testing and forgot to reset the env back to development using `RAILS_ENV=development`.

BTW, it's bad practice to set your local env to production like that. I only needed prod to execute the precompiler so doing this:

`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Which executes the command for the specific env w/out affecting the environment variable.